# Angular Date Incorrect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api2

I am using angular 1 with a webapi service.

I have a html5 date input on the page and if I select 2nd June 2018 I get the following JSON returned

> 2018-05-31T23:00:00.000Z

My computer and the server are set to GMT so why on earth is it removing an hour from the time?

Comment: Yep... That was my mistake. It is now edited to show the correct info

Comment: Lol... It is now correct above. It is the end of a hard day ;-)

Comment: Welcome to the bane of developers everywhere... date/time

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine. It returns as **(BST)** time - British **Summer** Time. The time is reduced by one hour == (UTC +1). `Sat Jun 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` == `"2018-06-01T23:00:00.000Z"`

---

Here is a demo of how time can be displayed:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = new Date("2018-06-02");
  $scope.check = function() {
    console.log($scope.test);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="date" ng-model="test">
  <button ng-click="check()">Click</button>
  <br>{{test}}
  <br>{{test | date}}
  <br>{{test | date:"fullDate"}}
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't BST at the moment... Surely Zulu time is GMT not BST(Which could change at a government decision)?

Comment: Ahh. I see what you are saying now. However Surely it should therefore return Sat Jun 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 not 2018-06-01T23:00:00.000Z?

Comment: @coolblue2000 it might be a good idea to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to automate/simplify most of the time (display) issues

Comment: How would this be done? Angular assumes I have picked a specific date. Is this not an issue with the HTML Date Input?

Comment: I am not sure how that helps. I know what date it is returning. It is just the incorrect date. In a date picker I want the date I picked not the date I picked minus 1 hour.

Comment: @coolblue2000 it's just depends on your local time, it will show you a different result. You can fix it by adding additional time with `.getTimezoneOffset()`